# Initial conditions of ODEs: Why is $\frac{}{} = \frac{1}{ \cdot ()}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I've started reading this [paper](https://github.com/Python-simulation/Black-hole-simulation-using-python/blob/master/Black%20hole%20simulation.pdf) (kindly check out the paper for more context, figure 1 provides a visualization of the problem) where it describes light trajectories on a Schwarzschild spacetime and stumbled upon the following formula:

$$\frac{}{} = \frac{1}{ \cdot ()}$$

Where $ = \frac{1}{}$, both $u$ and $\frac{}{}$ are the initial conditions of the second order differential orbital equation of the photon.

My question is why is that $\frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{D \cdot tan(\alpha)}$? Is there any intuition behind the formulation of this initial condition? And can it be geometrically or analytically proven?
I've asked this question on physics stack exchange and got no answer at all.

Comment: There is something smelly in the paper: (3) is not how you convert the 2rd order ODE (2) to a system of two 1st order equations. One equation should be $u'=v$, and the other $v'=3R_s/2u^2-u$. Here we don't even know what $v_0$ and $v_1$ are supposed to be, but I suspect $v_0=u, v_1=u'$ and the equations (3) should read $v_0'=\dots$ and $v_1'=\dots$.

Comment: Now, in *your* question, $\frac{1}{D \tan\alpha}$ is only an initial condition, it does not hold for all $\phi$. And if you want to understand *why* this initial condition holds, there is probably some physics to justify this, but it's not a mathematical question (in order to solve the ODE, we are given the initial condition, we don't really care where it comes from).